# Missing index of array

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this object

```
var offer = {
    'object': object,
    'description': description,
    'providers': providers,
    'value_min': value_min,
    'value_max': value_max,
    'owner': owner,
    'date': new Date().toISOString(),
    'status': 0,
    'id': idsSMS
  }
```

I record it on my firebase

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref().child('offers');

ref.push(offer);
```

result:

[image]

But when giving a get in these data, I have the following result:

```
ref.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
        data.push(snapshot.val())
        res.json(data);
   }
}
```

:

```
"-KqPP3A0oIlFVMOvrS0U": {
            "date": "2017-07-31T20:48:30.400Z",
            "description": "asdasd",
            "id": [
                "fb608080-8a27-1553-0bc1-f38f5850b253",
                "d9467847-8e11-38f6-1862-0d3f109d3cff"
            ],
```

ID array index disappeared.

In the firebase console it looks ok:

[image]

Comment: The index is only shown in some consoles. An array always has an index, depending on where you log it the index is explicitly shown, or not. You can still access the array values with `id[0]`, `id[1]`,...

Comment: yeah.. baao is right. This is similiar with java if  you use List data structure. So it is not missing

Comment: The Firebase Database natively stores arrays as JSON objects with sequential indexes. Its SDKs then converts those back to arrays when reading the database. See https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html

Comment: Thanks guys, my bad